# Rails 3 Nested Model Form, 2 levels deep using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3

My nested model form is working great on the first level deep.  But I was under the impression that you could go many levels deep using accepts_nested_attributes_for.  But when I try the code below, the "Image" attributes are attached to the top level "Question" model and it breaks upon form submission with an unknown attribute "Image" error.

I could do the inserts all by hand using the form data but if Rails can handle it automatically, it would be better for obvious reasons.

What am I doing wrong?  I tried changing |af| in the "fields for :image do" to its own unique name but it didn't have any effect.

Models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :answer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_one :image
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @question = Question.new
    answer = @question.build_answer
    image = answer.build_image

    @case_id = params[:id]

    render :layout => 'application', :template => '/questions/form' 
end

def create
  question_data = params[:question]
  @question = Question.new(question_data)
  if @question.save
  ...
end
```

View:

```
= form_for @question, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|

  = f.label :text, "Question Text:"
  = f.text_area :text, :rows => 7

  %br
  %br

  =f.fields_for :answer, do |af|
    = af.label :body, "Answer Text:"
    = af.text_area :body, :rows => 7

    %br
    %br

    = f.fields_for :image do |af|
      = af.label :title, "Image Title:"
      = af.text_field :title

      %br

      = af.label :file, "Image File:"
      = af.file_field :file

      %br

      = af.label :caption, "Image Caption:"
      = af.text_area :caption, :rows => 7

  = hidden_field_tag("case_id", value = @case_id)

  = f.submit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've got the form variables slightly mixed up. It should be:

```
= form_for @question, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|

  = f.label :text, "Question Text:"
  = f.text_area :text, :rows => 7

  %br
  %br

  =f.fields_for :answer, do |af|
    = af.label :body, "Answer Text:"
    = af.text_area :body, :rows => 7

    %br
    %br

    = af.fields_for :image do |img_form|
      = img_form.label :title, "Image Title:"
      = img_form.text_field :title

      %br

      = img_form.label :file, "Image File:"
      = img_form.file_field :file

      %br

      = img_form.label :caption, "Image Caption:"
      = img_form.text_area :caption, :rows => 7

  = hidden_field_tag("case_id", value = @case_id)

  = f.submit
```

Notice how `form_for ... do |f|` spawns `f.fields_for ... do |af|`, which in turns spawns `af.fields_for ... do |img_form|`.

The key is the second fields_for. It should be `af.fields_for :image do |img_form|` rather than `f.fields_for :image do |img_form|`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed that problem.  The only issue I have now is that when I submit the form, I get the form error "Answer question can't be blank."  I'm guessing this is because "Answer" has a required field called question_id that seems like it might not be getting filled out.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's correct. This is happening because the parent object (`Question`) is a new record and so it doesn't exist yet (i.e. doesn't have an id) when you try to save a child object (`Answer`). You can either remove your validation on question_id or in your controller, first save the parent object (`@question.save`) then the children (`@question.answers << @answer`). Something like that... For more info, check out this [article](http://hobocentral.net/blog/2008/04/29/activerecord-behaviour-with-associations/). HTH

Comment: It really can't just figure it out?  In the following Railscast (albeit for Rails 2.3) the author does what I'm trying to do with a simple @survey.new/@survey.save. [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)  For him, Rails just figured it all out and correctly did the association.  Does Rails 3 really no longer handle this?  Here is the github source code for his project: [link](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-196/surveysays)  Or am I doing something different?

Comment: Rails 3 should make no difference. I think the difference between what you have and the railscast is that you have a `validates_presence_of :question` in your `Answer` model. Try removing this validation.

Comment: Yeah, that got me to a new error with the image file uploader needing the case_id.  Basically what it comes down to is that I have to have that Case Id and I'll also need to have that answer_Id at some point to do this dynamically so I'll just make it simple and do it by hand and keep my validations.  Thank you so much for all your help!