# Woking with nested forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

**Company**
has_many :departments

**Department**
has_many :roles
belongs_to company

**Role**
belongs_to :department

I'm trying to create a dynamic page that takes company name, n number of departments that user adds dynamically(**rendering same partial as per button click**) and n number of roles inside each department(**rendering same partial as per button click**). I want to call like

```
form_for :company do |f|
```

= department_partial(rendered n times as per user), containing department form

```
form_for :department do |f|
```

= role_partial(rendered n times as per user), containing role form

```
form_for :role do |f|
```

so that when I click save once to call CompaniesController#Create

I get params like

{"company" => {"name" => "somename",
"department1" => {"name" => "somename", "role" => [{"name" => "R1"}, {"name" => "R2"}]},
"department2" => {"name" => "somename", "role" => [{"name" => "R1"}, {"name" => "R2"}, {"name" => "R3"}]}}

**NOTE**

1> Each department may have same roles repeated, but is distinct department wise.
2> Nothing is saved before I click save

Comment: What have you implemented ?

Comment: @Ajay 1> company partial has simple form with URL pointing to company create
2> department partial has form for department with text field(`f.text_field :name, name: "department[name][]"`)
3> role partial has (`fields_for "department[role][]", @role`)

But that not giving me desired params mentioned above

Comment: If you are using simple_form then you can also use simple_fields_for
here is the doc https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 1):

Please check [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Possibly your view will look something like this :

```
<%= nested_form_for @company do |comp| %>

   <!--  pick the company attributes --> 

   <%= comp.fields_for :departments do |department| %>
      <%= department.text_field :name %>

      <%= department.fields_for :roles do |role| %> 
          <!-- Pick your role attributes  --> 
       <% end %>

    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Take a look at this [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932934/rails-3-nested-model-form-2-levels-deep-using-accepts-nested-attributes-for#answer-5933056). this will help you :)
Check following railscast videos :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

and

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, isn't there a way to achieve this without the gem. And will it give the same params that I'm expecting(As mentioned in question)

Comment: Using nested_form will make things easy for you to handle those deep nesting(in your case too deep 3 layer, company, department, role)..
Regarding params,yes you will get in the nested format as you have show, you can put a raise statement in your controller & verify the coming parameters.

Comment: This works but I have a minor glitch. You see I have to render a partial each time I click "add new department" and pass the FormBuilder object (f). If I make it a ajax request to get the partial I'm unable to retrieve (f) from params as it converts it into string. What should I do?

Comment: am looking into it.. give me few minutes. :(