# Way to retrieve form builder object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for company that has `f.fields_for` for its associated table departments in **_department** partial.

My implementation is I may have n number of departments added dynamically to company form so I just call **_department** partial n number of times on button click through Ajax.

Here, I'm able to pass **f** in params something_path(:f => f) but unable to retrieve it as in params it becomes **String** type. How to retrieve it?

Comment: Use cocoon gem for that and your life will be easier :) https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: @BroiSatse Can you please answer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27957887/2968762). The above question is related to this.

Comment: please read the cocoon gem readme file, it will guide you how to do exactly what you want. You are getting closer! :) If you're stuck, post a new question with a specific problem rather than asking for the entire implementation.

Comment: @BroiSatse Actually I asked the specific question in comments. Since I can add the same partial dynamically n time, there will be n times f.fields_for for which I need to pass FormBuilder object f. Even cocoon gem requires (f) to be passed to the partial. How???

Comment: Not reallly. `fields_for` are intelligent enough to render it's block n times automatically if the parent's form object has n associated objects. With cocoon, you are not sending the partial with AJAX - the template is saved within `link_to_add_association` data fields. In short, you don't need to pass it via params.